# Создание текстового редактора как на Stackoverflow

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

у меня есть новостной сайт с админкой, сайт написан на PHP. И мне нужно сделать редактор текста постов, примерно как на stackoverflow. Можете подсказать через что это можно реализовать. Возможно есть какие-либо специальные библиотеки для этого или что-то подобное.

Comment: https://simplemde.com/

Comment: гуглите "wysiwyg", "rich text editor js" и т.п. из готового вдобавок - summernote, tinyMCE и т.п.